# Calling outer class function from inner class

Tags: java

I have implemented a nested class in Java, and I need to call the outer class method from the inner class.

```
class Outer {
    void show() {
        System.out.println("outter show");
    }

    class Inner{
        void show() {
            System.out.println("inner show");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call the `Outer` method `show`?

Comment: Can we assume that your inner class holds an instance of the outer class?

Comment: @Eric: in java, an instance of a non-static inner class ALWAYS holds an instance of the outer class

Comment: @Eric: that is always true in a non-static Java inner class!

Comment: Oops. I got mixed up. Can we assume that your _outer_ class holds an instance of the _inner_ class?

Comment: @Eric: I think you're even more mixed up now. No, you cannot assume that the outer class holds an instance of the inner class; but that's irrelevant to the question. You're first question (whether the inner class holds an instance of the outer class) *was* the relevant question; but the answer is yes, always.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You need to prefix the call by the outer class:

```
Outer.this.show();
```

Comment: Great. I have a follow up on this. How do I call a method in the outer class from a totally different place by having an inner class instance. Inner myInner = new Outer().new Inner();  ... for example if the outer class has a public method getValue(). myInner.getValue() wouldnt work, myInner.Outer.getValue() doesn't either. I know I can do it by having a method getOwner in Inner and then call it.. but do  I need that method? thanks

Comment: If outer is an interface then how to call the abstract method from inner class..?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Outer.Inner obj = new Outer().new Inner();
obj.show();
```

Comment: He was asking about show() method of Outer class, this call will invoke Inner class's show().