# calling a function in a class's "owner" class

Tags: java

Following pseudocode sums up my question pretty well I think...

```
class Owner {
    Bar b = new Bar();

    dostuff(){...}
}    

class Bar {
    Bar() {
        //I want to call Owner.dostuff() here
    }
}
```

`Bar b` is 'owned' (whats the proper word?) by `Owner` (it 'has a'). So how would an object of type `Bar` call `Owner.dostuff()`?

At first I was thinking `super();`, but that's for inherited classes. Then I was thinking pass an interface, am I on the right track?

Comment: No. if it's a non-static method you need an instance.

Comment: @jason, suppose two classes have a field with the same reference to `b`?  Which then would be the "owner"?

Comment: so pass a reference of Owner to Bar?

Comment: @Kirk I guess both would share ownership.

Comment: @jason, right, but my point is that in such a scenario the concept of calling something on *the* "Owner" is nonsensical.

Comment: @KirkWoll As other answers have noted, I'm more and more inclined to think that OP really wants an inner class.

Comment: I think the best way to name "Owner class" is to use the term "Enclosing class", but I've heard it called "container class" as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If dostuff is a regular method you need to pass Bar an instance.

```
class Owner {

   Bar b = new Bar(this);

   dostuff(){...}
}    

class Bar {
   Bar(Owner owner) {
      owner.dostuff();
   }
}
```

Note that there may be many owners to Bar and not any realistic way to find out who they are.

Edit: 
You might be looking for an Inner class: 
Sample and comments.

```
class Owner {

   InnerBar b = new InnerBar();

   void dostuff(){...}

   void doStuffToInnerBar(){
       b.doInnerBarStuf();
   }

   // InnerBar is like a member in Owner.
   class InnerBar { // not containing a method dostuff.
      InnerBar() { 
      // The creating owner object is very much like a 
      // an owner, or a wrapper around this object.
      }
      void doInnerBarStuff(){
         dostuff(); // method in Owner
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @jason. If owner is an important concept for Bar, you might look in to the Inner class others have mentioned. This basically would make Bar a member in Owner.

Comment: I dislike that this (like all answers so far) is tight coupling: `Bar` should not know about the `Owner` type except for that one function (declaration) it wants to talk to. Reusing `Bar` elsewhere gets complicated this way. Not sure how a simple "event property" aught to be done in JAVA though, it may need a bunch of Listeners code.

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
class Owner {

    Bar b = new Bar(this);

    dostuff(){...}
}    

class Bar {
    Bar(Owner myOwner) {
        myOwner.dostuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for nested Clases
[Nested Classes Sun](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

This way u can write `outer.this.doStuff();`

Have a look to that topic: [Inner class call outer class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808501/calling-outer-class-function-from-inner-class)

Comment: Ahh yes, this may work for my situation as well, thank you for reminding me of it.

Answer (score 2):

In the way you're putting it, there is no way of calling the "owner" in Java.

Object A has a reference of object B doesn't mean that object B even knows that object A exists.

The only way to achieve this would be either though inheritance (like you said yourself), or by passing an instance of object Owner to the constructor of Bar.

Comment: "object B doesn't mean that object B even knows that object A exists" - Ive always thought this was odd. Some things work when theyre mutually aware, but I need to remember that this is not the default way it works. Was also secretly hoping for some mystical java-fu that I missed.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Owner {
    Bar b = null;
    Owner(){
       b = new Bar(this);
    }
    dostuff(){...}
}    

class Bar {
    Owner o = null;
    Bar(Owner o) {
        this.o = o;
    }
}
```

Now, instance `b` of `Bar` has a reference to `o` of type `Owner` and can do `o.doStuff()` whenever needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Owner {

    Bar b = new Bar(this);

    dostuff(){...}
}    

class Bar {
    Bar(Owner owner) {
       owner.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you have written the code, it is not possible to do. But if you declare Bar as [***inner class***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) of Owner, you might get a closer solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possibilities :

1) making dostuff() static and call it like

```
Owner.dostuff()
```

2) Creating an instance of Owner inside the class Bar

```
class Bar {
   Owner o;
   public Owner() {
     o = new Owner();
     o.dostuff();
   }
}
```

3) Inject an Owner instance through the constructor

```
class Bar {
   public Owner(Owner o) {
     o.dostuff();
   }
}
```