# Java call a function outside a class

Tags: java, oop, class, function

Is there a way to call a function outside a class? I don't know how to say it but I have an example.

```
class Class1{
    class Class2{
          public void callFunctionInC1(){
                //how can I call funtionNeedtoBeCalled
          }
    }
    public Class1(){
          Class2 c2 = new Class2();
          c2.callFunctionInC1();
    }
    public void functionNeedtoBeCalled(){
          //do something
    }
 }
```

It sounds weird but I do have a reason to do that. Is there anyway to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Class1.this.functionNeedtoBeCalled()

Comment: Are you using inner classes in your *real* situation, or did the example just come out this way? It makes a big difference.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, in my real solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Class1.this.functionNeedtoBeCalled();
```

Here is a link with some more discussion. http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t137884-inner-class-explicit-outer-class-method-call.html

[Calling outer class function from inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808501/calling-outer-class-function-from-inner-class)

Comment: haha, +1, I think Boris Treukhov was even faster in his comment.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: `Class1.this.functionNeedtoBeCalled();`