# How to access parent class member from nested class in Java?

Tags: java

Simple question for Java programmer - I am not sure if it possible directly - please present workarounds.

I want to access parent variable to initialize nested class member but not know the Java syntax to do it (if it possible). How to set Child id with parent id.

```
public class Parent {
    final String id = "parent";

    class Child {
        // it is invalid since scope hide parent id?
        final String id = id;
    }
}
```

The best solution with I found is very ugly see here:

```
public class Parent {
    final String id = "parent";

    // ugly clone
    String shadow = id;

    class Child {
        final String id = shadow;
    }
}
```

Please help with syntax - I do not know how to express it.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can access it by using its fully qualified name:

```
final String id = Parent.this.id;
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, your field is assigned using a method?

Comment: I will make other question you guessed this so should give you points :)

Comment: it is always `ClassNameOfOuterClass.this.someMemberOrMethodOfOuter` - with or without () at the end. Speaking of which - I would call it outer and inner class.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808501/calling-outer-class-function-from-inner-class) by the way.

Comment: Not the same I will post some other question since asked about somethign other than want and get valid answer but little different.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if the outer class name collides with the inner class name?

Comment: Does that still work if the parent class is generic? e.g. Parent<T> would be referenced like Parent.this.id ?

Answer (score -6):

How about if you change one of the String id.

```
public class Parent {
  final String id = "parent";

  class Child {
    // it is invalid since scope hide parent id?
    // Instead of using id use ID
    final String ID = id;
  }
}
```

This way you would not have string id = id, which does not make sense.

Comment: This is  not a valid solution. The OP wants to use the same variable names. your suggestion is already demonstrated by OP.