# Invoking methods of a class that instantiated this one

Tags: java, methods, inner-classes, outer-classes, resource-loading

I'm developing a game in Java which uses the Lightweight Java Game Library (LWJGL) with OpenGL.

I encountered the following problem.

I want to create an ArrayList of all textures in an object in the main loop, and access these from objects instantiated in this main object. A simplified example:

**game.class:**

```
public class Game {

  ArrayList Textures; // to hold the Texture object I created
  Player player; // create Player object

  public Game() {
    new ResourceLoader(); // Here is the instance of the ResourceLoader class
    player = new Player(StartingPosition) // And an instance of the playey, there are many more arguments I give it, but none of this matter (or so I hope)

    while(true) { // main loop
      // input handlers

      player.draw() // here I call the player charcter to be drawn

    }
  }

  // this method SHOULD allow the resource loader to add new textures
  public void addTextures (Texture tx) {
    Textures.add(tx);
  }
}
```

**ResourceLoader.class**

```
public class ResourceLoader {
  public ResourceLoader() {
    Interface.this.addTexture(new Texture("image.png")); // this is the line I need help with
  }
}
```

**Player.class**

```
public class Player {
  public player() {
    // some stuff, including assignment of appropriate textureID
  }

  public void draw() {
    Interface.this.Textures.get(this.textureID).bind(); // this also doesn't work
    // OpenGL method to draw the character
  }
}
```

In my real code the `ResourceLoader` class has about 20 textures to load.

There is a total of over 400 entities in the game that have a draw method just like `Player.class` and most of them share the same texture; e.g. there are about 150-180 wall object all showing the same image of bricks.

The `Game` object is not the main class and it does not have the `static void main()` method, but it is one of the only few things instantiated in the `main()` method of the game.

Also, in the past, I worked around the problem by letting each entity load its own texture file. But as I increased the complexity and map size, it becomes very inefficient to load the same image hundreds of times.

I arrived at the state of the code above from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808501/calling-outer-class-function-from-inner-class) answer.

I believe I would have to put `ResourceLoader.class` and `Player.class` inside the `game.class`, which would not be a good solution considering that there are about 20 files that need this treatment and most of them are 200+ lines long.

I think my `Texture` object as well as initialization of OpenGL and other stuff are pretty generic and should not impact the issue in question. I can provide these if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the "outer" class instance a parameter to the constructors:

```
public class Player {
   final Interface obj;

   public player(Interface obj) {
       this.obj = obj;
      // some stuff, including assignment of appropriate textureID
   }

   public void draw() {
       obj.Textures.get(this.textureID).bind();
   }
}

public class ResourceLoader {
   public ResourceLoader(Interface obj) {
      obj.addTexture(new Texture("image.png"));
   }
}
```

And instantiate those in `Game` like:

```
new Player(this);
```

Note: The example lines used `Interface` but `Game` does not implement it. I assume that's an artifact of code cleaned for the posting. Just use the type that is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! For anyone who want's to use this method remember that you have to initialize the `ArrayList` (I did forget that when creating this thread) also, `Game` is the `Interface`, I just forgot to change those 2 lines while I was cleaning the code, sorry.