# Connect ActionListener with methods in other class

Tags: java, swing

So I have two classes: "Simulator" and "SimulationWindow".
Simulator holds all methods and functions the Simulator uses and also defines an instance of SimulationWindow.

SimulationWindow makes the GUI. In this GUI I have 4 JButtons. These buttons should call methods implemented in Simulator. But how can I connect the buttons with the listener?

```
button1.addActionListener( ??? );
```

I struggle because my program has a main class to start the Simulator:

```
Simulator sim1 = new Simulator();
```

So I have this object Simulator and cannot create another one in SimulationWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the reference to your Simulator to the SimulationWindow's constructor and save it in a field there:

In Simulator:

```
class Simulator {
    private final SimulationWindow window;

    public Simulator() {
        window = new SimulationWindow(this);
    }

    ...
}
```

In SimulationWindow:

```
class SimulationWindow extends JFrame { 
    private final Simulator sim;

    public SimulationWindow(Simulator sim) {
        this.sim = sim;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you can access `sim` within the instance of SimulationWindow and within the ActionListeners you add there.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the `actionPerformed` method in the inner class(`SimulationWindow`) and have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808501/calling-outer-class-function-from-inner-class) on how to call outer class(`Simulator`) methods from the inner class context.

Comment: I tried this, getting "No enclosing instance of the type Simulator is accessible in scope" - Error.