# How can I call a method of an outer class if my inner class implements something different than the outer class?

Tags: java, class, methods, nested

My code looks like this:

```
class A {
      void myMethod() {
      ...
      }

      class B implements class C {
      // ... how can I call myMethod here?
      }
}
```

I am sorry if I'm not explicit enough or if there is any error in my question.

Comment: Myself, I really don't know what your question is. Can you show us real code as well as give more concrete information about your problem.

Comment: Inner class instances have an implicit reference to their enclosing instances. You can directly use `myMethod();`.

Comment: Did my answer work? Feel free to ask me any questions if it didn't. If it did, make sure to mark it best answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the method directly:

```
class A {
  void myMethod() {
  ...
  }

  class B implements class C {
    public void init() {
      myMethod(); // calls myMethod() from A
    }
  }
}
```

In that case that class B also has a method named "myMethod", then see this question: [Calling outer class function from inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808501/calling-outer-class-function-from-inner-class)

```
class A {
  void myMethod() {
  ...
  }

  class B implements class C {
    public void init() {
      // calls myMethod from A even tho myMethod is also defined on B
      A.this.myMethod();
    }

    void myMethod() {
    }
  }
}
```

I can only guess that this answers your question, but it's hard to tell since you didn't provide the actual code that you had the problem with.

Answer (score -1):

Use this to run a method in a different class:

```
class.method();
```

This will run method method in class class.

If the method you wanted to call was in the same class you were calling it from you could just write the method name:

```
method();
```