# How to convert lambda for swap param to a method

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand how lambda is work. In the process i found this example.

```java
public class Calculator {
   interface IntegerMath {
      int operation(int a, int b);

      default IntegerMath swap() {
         return (a, b) -> operation(b, a);
      }
   }

   private static int apply(int a, int b, IntegerMath op) {
      return op.operation(a, b);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      IntegerMath addition =  (a, b) -> a + b;
      Math subtraction = (a, b) -> a - b;

      System.out.println(apply(5, 10, subtraction));
      System.out.println(apply(5, 10, subtraction.swap()));
   }
}
```

I'm trying to convert the swap method implementation from lambda to normal method.

But i cant change that, because if i did that i should write the implementation of operation method and create an infinity recursive.

```java
public class Calculator {
   interface IntegerMath {
      int operation(int a, int b);

      default IntegerMath swap() {
         return new IntegerMath() {
            @Override
            public int operation(int a, int b) {
               return operation(b, a);
            }
         };
      }
   }
}
```

Can i not use lambda in swap method in interface IntegerMath?

Comment: Could you try to rephrase the question please? It's not really clear what you're asking. Your fist code block is not valid Java. Should it be `public interface Calculator`?

Comment: You are returning different things in each implementation. swap() returns a *function* that can be later called. Your implementation of swap() simply won't work because it will infinitely recurse and wants to return a *value* not a function.

Comment: @mypetlion sorry my bad. i have fixed my question

Comment: @RyanSchaefer you are right. can i not use lambda in method swap in IntegerMath interface

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling outer class function from inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808501/calling-outer-class-function-from-inner-class)

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to call the outer `operation()` from within your anonymous implementation, you can do it like this:

```
return IntegerMath.this.operation(b, a);
```

Comment: sorry, i have fixed my question. i don't think that works?

Comment: Why don't you think so? Did you try it?

Comment: i'm try it. but i don't exactly understand your answer, maybe i'm wrong. where i can do that?

Comment: How can you do what?

Comment: sorry i'm not. i just cant explaining my problem clear enough. check my edited question. i want to change the swap method in IntegerMath interface without using lambda.

Comment: I understood the question. But I don't understand what problem you're having with the answer.

Comment: in example code i can call subtraction.swap() and the output from that two is different, so the swap method is work using lambda. but what if i don't want to use lambda. in confuse how to implement your answer in swap method. because when i use your answer to replace the lambda it doesn't work. or i have to create anonymous class that implement operation and use your answer but it show warning infinite recursion