# how to refer same method from (non static) inner to outer class

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have a (non static) inner class and have a same method within both the inner and the outer class. How can I call the outer method within the inner method?

```
class User{

    public void call() {
        ...
    }
    
    public class Admin{
        public void call() {
            // I want to refer to User#call, not to Admin#call()
           // super.call() does not work here, because no inheritance
            call(); // refers to Admin#call
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling outer class function from inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808501/calling-outer-class-function-from-inner-class)

Comment: Already answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By applying the class name to "this":

```
User.this.call()
```